# Doing a get request in Java causes HTTP response code: 415

Tags: java, http

I'm trying to retrieve information from a webservice using the following code:

```
String kenteken = request.getParameter("InputKenteken");
        String uri = String.format("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/opendata.rdw/VRTG.Open.Data/v1/KENT_VRTG_O_DAT('%s')", kenteken);

        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/html");
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream xml = connection.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = null;
         try {
             db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
         } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(CarServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
         try {
             Document doc = db.parse(xml);
         } catch (SAXException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(CarServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
      }
```

I keep getting 415 response code when I call the URL from code while the URL works fine in chrome.

[image]

This is the URL I used:

https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/opendata.rdw/VRTG.Open.Data/v1/KENT_VRTG_O_DAT('jnzd27')

Comment: The code you have for parsing the response does not appear to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [415 response code](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E415.html) indicates that the media type which is requested is not supported. If you look in the response headers of chrome you can see that the returned content-type is:

```
  Content-Type:application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8
```

It seems that accepting this exact content type resolves the problem. Thus instead of:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/html");
```

use:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/atom+xml");
```

Comment: Using connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/atom+xml"); solved the issue, thank you!